# how to catch Sequelize connection error

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

How to catch a sequelize connection error in case there is one?

I tried to do

```
var connection = new Sequelize("db://uri");
connection.on("error", function() { /* perhaps reconnect here */ });
```

but apparently this is not supported.

I wanted to do this because I think sequelize might be throwing an occasional unhandled ETIMEOUT and crashing my node process.

Currently I am using sequelize to connect a mysql instance. I only need it for like 2-3 hours and during that time I will be doing a many read queries. The mysql server will not be connected to anything else during that time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using sync() for this is considerably dangerous when using external migrations or when database integrity is paramount (when isn't it!)

The more [up-to-date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31115934) way of doing this is to use `authenticate()`

```
sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sequelize sync method provides an easy way to catch the error.
The then block handles a Successful connection and the catch handles the rejection.To get a detailed reason for a failure access the error object.
example: `error.message e.t.c`
Hope this helps.

```
   sequelize.sync().
then(function() {
  console.log('DB connection sucessful.');
}).catch(err=> console.log('error has occured'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Same answer just using async/await

```
try {
  await sequelize.authenticate()
} catch (err) {
  console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use sequelize sync for that

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, {
    'host' : config.host,
    'dialect' : config.dialect,
    'port' : config.port,
    'logging' : false
  })

sequelize.sync().then(function(){
  console.log('DB connection sucessful.');
}, function(err){
  // catch error here
  console.log(err);

});
```

Comment: Cool thanks I will try it out. I did sequelize.authenticate().then(resolve, reject) before and the reject was never invoked.