# Sequelize.authenticate() do not working (no success or error response) for google cloud sql connection inside Docker

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, sequelize.js, google-cloud-sql

I am building api server with typescript ,express and `Sequelize`.

This is my `database` connection class.

```
export class Database {
  private _sequelize: Sequelize;
  private config: DBConfigGroup = dbConfig;
  private env = process.env.NODE_ENV as string;

  constructor() {
    this._sequelize = new Sequelize({
      dialect: 'postgres',
      database: this.config[this.env].database,
      username: this.config[this.env].username,
      password: this.config[this.env].password,
      host: this.config[this.env].host,
    });
  }

  async connect(): Promise<void> {
    try {
      console.log('start connect');
      await this._sequelize.authenticate();
      console.log('Connection has been established successfully.'.green.bold);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Unable to connect to the database:'.red.bold, error);
    }
  }

  async close(): Promise<void> {
    try {
      await this._sequelize.close();
      console.log('Connection has been close successfully.'.red.bold);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Unable to close to the database:'.yellow.bold, error);
    }
  }

  get sequelize(): Sequelize {
    return this._sequelize;
  }
}
```

So in my `server.ts`, i was calling this

```
dotenv.config({
  path: './config/environments/config.env',
});

const database = new Database();
console.log('Init db');
database
  .connect()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('success db ininit');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('fail db init: ', err);
  }); 

/**
 * Server Activation
 */
const server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${PORT}`.yellow.bold);
});
```

So everythings works fine in my local development

But when i try to run it with `docker compose` with this config

```
// docker-compose.yml
version: '3.4'

services:
  api:
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    build:
      context: ./api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./api:/app
```

This is my `Dockerfile.dev` file

```
FROM node:alpine

ENV NODE_ENV=development

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 5000

COPY package.json package-lock.json* ./ 

RUN npm install && npm cache clean --force

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev:docker"]
```

But the problem is when i run `docker-compose up --build`

I only see these logs

```
api_1  | Init db
api_1  | start connect
api_1  | Server running in development mode on port 5000
```

So basiccally there is no response whether `sequelize.authenticate()` is success or fail, 
just `Server running in development mode on port 5000` log out and nothing after all.

Why don't it works inside docker like in the local, any config that i missed?

Thanks

Comment: Probably you can't reach the database from there (different network, wrong IP/DNS name, DB not listenening on that interface, firewall rule, whatever), and if you'd wait for a minute or two, you'd get a failure with a timeout error. You didn't show the dbConfig - what is the host/port?

Comment: @CherryDT host is the ip of google sql and port should not be matter isn't it?
Also i can connect successfully with normal localhost connection, think i should missed some config for my docker.

Comment: What is in `Dockerfile.dev`?

Comment: @TarunLalwani already in the question.

Comment: @VarisDarasirikul, sorry I meant to ask for the environment variables and not the Dockerfile

Comment: Ah sorry I missed that it was about Google Cloud SQL, I thought maybe the SQL server was localhost.

Comment: @TarunLalwani config is just a simple js object, even i try with const object, still not working anyway.

Comment: > host is the ip of google sql 

Can you share what this IP is?

I'm guessing you are not running the `cloud_sql_proxy`, are you?

Comment: @BYK this is the public ip `34.69.33.26` , i doubt that the issue is about `sequalize` itself, since if i change to `mySql` (on different instance) with same config, it works fine.

Comment: Maybe this helps you then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38650200/how-to-catch-sequelize-connection-error#comment64705215_38650447

Comment: @VarisDarasirikul Recently there was a similar issue reported for Node 14 https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/12158, check it. Try updating your pg module version

Answer (score 20):

You can try node:10 version
I have same issue but when change image to node:10, that issue is gone
Hope to help you

Comment: It's weird but I did same and it's started working. Do you know the reason behind this?

Comment: @Amolpskamble I think conflict Sequelize and Node version

Comment: Had the same problem and indeed specifying another version of node was the solution.
Mine was ```node:alpine``` changed to ```node:13.12.0-alpine3.10```

Comment: oh gosh, thank you. I had the same problem and thought I was going crazy. Knowing the culprit, I found an [issue on sequelize's GitHub.](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/12158) The conflict is due to an outdated pg dependency that breaks due to an undocumented change in node - [more explanation and references here](https://github.com/codimd/server/commit/d6ce60c86e714b9835822e8539470b21b8fb823c) - if you upgrade pg to 8.0.3 you don't need to downgrade node

Comment: I was on node version 14 and had the exact same issue on mac. Downgraded to 12.6.0 it worked

Comment: I was going crazy and just saw this. My problem is fixed when I downgraded from node 14 to 12.12.

Comment: I struggled a lot (7-8 days), but the solution is just changed node version to node:12-12-alpine and pg to 8.0.3. Solution is change versions for node or pg will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Latest node version v14.15.5 is now throwing an error for this problem. It is instructing to install pg locally

```
/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:81
    throw new Error(`Please install ${moduleName} package manually`);
          ^
```

Error: Please install pg package manually

I did that and fixed the problem on my machine.